# Sending data from another controller to another View MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm tring to send the data from Another Controller to another View.
I have a Home Controller but I don't want to send to Home View data because I need this data in Car View where I get dropdownlist from database

Home COntroller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Data.Entity;
using Automarket.Models;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using static System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames;

namespace Automarket.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        OurDBContext db = new OurDBContext();
        // Controller for populate dropdownlist
        // GET: Home
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Price()
        {
            OurDBContext db = new OurDBContext();
            ViewBag.price = new SelectList(db.prices, "Id", "price");
            return View("Car");
        }


    }
}
```

Car View

```
@using Automarket.Models;
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    List<Marke> marke = ViewData["marke"] as List<Marke>;
    List<Modeli> modeli = ViewData["modeli"] as List<Modeli>;

    string deps = ViewData["deps"] as string;
}

<h2>Automarket</h2>



<div>

    @Html.DropDownList("Prices" , "--Select Item--")
</div>






    <div class="dropdown">
        <select id="brand" onchange="popMod(@deps)" name="brand" class="form-control">
            @foreach (var mrka in marke)
            {
                <option value="@mrka.Id">@mrka.Name</option>
            }
        </select>
    </div>



<p>
    <select id="modeli" name="model" class="form-control">
        @foreach (var modell in modeli)
        {
            <option value="@modell.Id">@modell.Name</option>
        }
    </select>
</p>








<script>

    function popMod(mo) {
        var mod = document.getElementById("modeli");
        var len = mod.length;
        while (mod.options.length > 0) {
            mod.remove(0);
        }
        var sel = document.getElementById("brand");
        var id = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
        for (el in mo) {
            if (mo[el].MarkeId == id) {
                var op=document.createElement("option");
                op.value=mo[el].Id;
                op.innerHTML=mo[el].Name;
                mod.appendChild(op);

            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: `@Html.DropDownList("Prices" , "--Select Item--",(SelectList)ViewBag.price)` this doesn't work?

Comment: Use the full path of Car View like View("~\View\CarFolder\CarView.cshtml"). It will then go to Car View and you can get your ViewBag,ViewData or TempData values here.

Comment: I get this error: There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'Prices'.